# How to get the text from the text box and compare it?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing a website to learn Italian and my problem is when I try to get the answers from a text-box and do the percentage, it always gives me 0% even if i answered them right!

```js
var ri = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
var res=0;
var rest;
 function input(){
     ri[0] = document.getElementsByName("r1").value;
     ri[1] = document.getElementsByName("r2").value;
     ri[2] = document.getElementsByName("r3").value;
     ri[3] = document.getElementsByName("r4").value;
     ri[4] = document.getElementsByName("r5").value;
     checkAnswers();
 }
function input(){
    if(ri[0]=="abitiamo"){
        res=res+1;
    }
    if(ri[1]=="frequentate"){
       res=res+1;         
    }
    if(ri[2]=="suonano"){
       res=res+1;
    }
    if(ri[3]=="trovi"){
       res=res+1;
    }
    if(ri[4]=="studia"){
       res=res+1;
    }
    output();        
}

function output(){
    rest = res*100/ri.length;
    alert(rest+"%");
    res=0;
    rest=0;
}
```

```html
<p style="font-size: large;">
    1. Noi <input type="text" name="r1" style="width: 86px;"> (abitare) a Roma <br>        
    2. Che scuola <input type="text" name="r2" style="width: 86px;"> (frequentare) voi, Gianni e Tommaso?<br>    
    3. Marina e Lucia <input type="text" name="r3" style="width: 86px;"> (suonare) bene il piano. <br>
    4. Luca, tu <input type="text" name="r4" style="width: 86px;"> (trovare) delle informazioni interessanti in questa lezione?<br>     
    5. Luciana <input type="text" name="r5" style="width: 86px;"> (studiare) filosofia a Milano. <br>
</p>               
<button onclick="input()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: You have two functions named `input`. And getElementsByName returns a NodeList. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution:

```js
var answers = ["abitiamo", "frequentate", "suonano", "trovi", "studia"];
var correctCount = 0;
var result;

function input() {
  correctCount = 0;
  result=0;
  for (i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
    var textBox = document.getElementsByName("r" + (i + 1))[0];
    if (textBox.value == answers[i]) {
      correctCount++;
    }
  }
  result = correctCount * 100 / answers.length;
  alert(result + "%");
}
```

```html
<p style="font-size: large;">
    1. Noi <input type="text" name="r1" style="width: 86px;"> (abitare) a Roma <br>
    2. Che scuola <input type="text" name="r2" style="width: 86px;"> (frequentare) voi, Gianni e Tommaso?<br>
    3. Marina e Lucia <input type="text" name="r3" style="width: 86px;"> (suonare) bene il piano. <br>
    4. Luca, tu <input type="text" name="r4" style="width: 86px;"> (trovare) delle informazioni interessanti in questa lezione?<br>
    5. Luciana <input type="text" name="r5" style="width: 86px;"> (studiare) filosofia a Milano. <br>
  </p>
  <button onclick="input()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: If you update your answer to be more dynamic with the suggested change, I will be happy to delete my previous comment and add a +1. :)